# SImple Drupal 7 online store (send email to clients, no online payments)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

i want to create a simple online store using Drupal 7, and i just need to send an email for the client after choosing the item (with info about the items). no need to pay online or anything.

is there any module that does that? if not how can i build such module?

Comment: Look into hook_mail. You should also consider posting questions about Drupal at http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience with https://drupal.org/project/commerce?  It can be a bit daunting to figure out but in combination with https://drupal.org/project/payment and a simple rule to send an email you could accomplish this without having to write any code.  There are excellent tutorials at http://www.drupalcommerce.org/ that should be able to get you started